# Are we obliged to say Kiddush Levana or is it in some way optional?

Tags: halacha, kiddush-levanah

The [laws of Kiddush Levana](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49626&st=&pgnum=183) start with the words 
הרואה לבנה בחדושה….
“Someone who sees the moon when it is renewed…..”

This might imply that if one deliberately keeps away from seeing the moon, one is not obliged to say Kiddush Levana..

So, am I obligated to go and see if the moon is visible so I can make the brocho or do I make the brocho only if by chance I see the moon?

Comment: One of the Rabbanim of our Shul quoted Harav Shelomo Aviner saying that that it is a Hiyuv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a machlokes amongst the Achronim regarding if the Bracha of Kiddush Levanah is #1 made to celebrate the "renewal of the world i.e the new moon - this is the loshon of the Mishne Berurah) OR #2 because we derive benefit (i.e. we can see) from the moons light. The practical difference between these two reasons is a blind person. If the reason is to cerebrate the new moon than the blind person should say the bracha. If the reason is benefit the blind person derives no direct benefit (although he does benefit from other people who benefit from the light of the moon so he should say a blessing according to some Achronim)

Now in your case if you for what ever reason don't want to look at the moon - according to the Mishne Beruah who goes with reason #1 you still have to make the Brachah since you are no different than a blind person in this case. If with modern city lighting you still benefit from the moons light than even according to reason #2 you would have to make the Bracha but my experience is that the city lights drown out the effect of the moon. Seeing the the Biur Halacha makes a case for blind people not to say the Bracha you might want to ask your Rabbi if it's appropriate for someone to be motzai you in the Bracha.

[Source SA 426](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49626&st=&pgnum=183)

I would be remiss if I didn't point out what a special Mitzvah Kiddush Levanah is and that one should try their hardest to say it on time and with a minyan.

Comment: See sefer Ishei Yisrael pg 463 footnote 2 ,machlokes either bircas hashecach,haneinen or bircas jamitzvos,see aruch Hashulchan