# Kiddush Levana the night of Purim

Tags: purim, megillat-esther, priorities, kiddush-levanah

It is the night of Purim and for some reason the majority of the Shul has not yet said Kiddush Levana. Should Kiddush Levana be said prior to Megila due to "Tadur" it being more frequent? (source)

Comment: unless theyre davening outside, this http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29698/759 is highly relevant to an argument from Tadir

Answer (score 1):

[Noda B'Yehuda 41 - page 44 - column starting with Vnashiv](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1497&st=&pgnum=52) says that they should make Kiddush Levana first for two reasons. One is tadir. The other is that the Megila can always be done later, however Kiddush Levana there is a risk of it getting cloudy.

Comment: A great Tshuva. very impressive

Answer (score 1):

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 97:15 writes that kiddush levana should be recited before megillah. However, he notes that if a tzibur is in middle of reading the megillah and the moon is now visible they should be mafsik and go out to say the bracha,and then go back inside and resume the megillah.  However, if it is just a yachid(individual) then he should forgo kiddush levana because pirsumei nisa is more important.

Text of KSA:

אם בחודש אדר לא נראתה עד ליל ארבעה עשר, שהוא זמן קריאת המגילה, יקדשו תחילה את הלבנה, ואחר כך יקראו את המגילה. ואם נראתה באמצע קריאת המגילה, אם הוא בזמן שגם לאחר שיגמרו את הקריאה, יהיה עוד שהות לקדשה, אין מפסיקין באמצע קריאת המגילה. אבל אם עד שיגמרו את המגילה יעבור זמנה, אזי אם כל הקהל עדיין לא קידשו אותה, יפסיקו לקדש אותה, ואחר כך יגמרו את המגילה. אבל אם רק יחיד לא קידש אותה, שאם יפסיק לקדשה, יצטרך אחר כך לגמור את המגילה ביחידות, לא יפסיק, משום דפרסומי ניסא עדיף.